# Select all rows from two tabels

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am new to database design and am working on school project. I have 3 tables (`Users`, `Roles` and `User_roles`). I have created all the users and the roles that are available for the users. I have created the `User_roles` table which contains the users and the roles that have been assigned to them.

I need to get a query that will give me all the users, all the roles available and if they allocated to the users. My aim is to list all the available users and available roles so that I can assign or remove the rights to access.

How do I achieve this?

The following is the schema of tables

```
Users
 (
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active' ,
  `date_from` DATE NULL ,
  `date_to` DATE NULL ,
  `created_by` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Sysadmin' ,
  `create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now() ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)

Roles Tables
`role_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `role_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `date_from` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01' ,
  `date_to` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '2999-12-31' ,
  `created_by` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Sysadmin' ,
  `create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now() ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`) 

User_role Table
`user_role_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `role_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_role_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_User_roles_Users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
    REFERENCES `Users` (`user_id` )
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_User_roles_Roles1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`role_id` )
    REFERENCES `Roles` (`role_id` )
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade
```

My aim is to select all users from table users and show the roles available to be allocated and if allocated

for example

```
User_id      Role_id      Role_allocated
```

Something similar

Comment: can you show sample records and desired result in tabular format?

Comment: without desired output and sample structure how can we understand. Also post what you have tried yet.

Comment: Not able to understand without the schema.

Comment: @Nikhil ,@JW ,@raheel-shan

I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use sql join on condition as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM User_roles as ur 
INNER JOIN Users as u on ur.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN Roles as r on ur.role_id = r.role_id;
```

assuming primary key for tables as : Users => user_id, Roles => role_id. This query will return all the users and it's roles that is assigned in User_roles table. It would have been easier to answer your question if you had provided keys and other attributes of tables.